# Static Scope and Dynamic Scope

Tags: language-agnostic, scope, dynamic-scope

I have this program:

```
var a, b:integer

procedure sub () 

var a,b:real;

begin

…

end

procedure sub1() 

var c:integer

begin

   …a…b…

end

begin

…

end
```

1. With static scoping, a and b in sub1 are in main?
2. With dynamic scoping, and with chain: main → sub → sub → sub1. Which variables a and b used in sub1?

Comment: Thank you! I'm a newbie.

Comment: 1) no. 2) it depends specific language specifications, you can't make it language agnostic.

Comment: Oh, what about **pascal** ?

Comment: Pascal has not dynamic scoping...

Comment: Oh, thank you. I have some trouble about this. Heyaaa, thank any way

Comment: BTW pick a language like Perl where you have both types, you can try by yourself (you'll see that, beside basics of dynamic scoping, you'll find rules only for Perl itself as you can't compare rules for C and JavaScript even if they're both lexically scoped)